# Conversion from math mode of the form $x_a$ to text?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, font-encodings

I want to convert from italic math mode `$x_a$` to upright. So I thought `\text{x_a}` would do. But due to the underscore sign it doesn’t work. Any ideas?

Comment: `\mathrm`, perhaps?

Comment: `$\mathrm{x}_\mathrm{a}$` ?

Comment: `x\textsubscript{a}`; but it's unclear what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\text{x_a}` will not do because, unsurprisingly, `\text{...}` puts us in text mode and `_` is valid only in math mode.

So it depends what you want to do. If you want a subscript in text, you should use `\textsubscript{...}`, which still requires the `fixltx2e` package for me, although I think the LaTeX 3 project is planning to incorporate native support for this. (Indeed, egreg points out in the comments that `\textsubscript{...}` was incorporated in the 2015/01/01 kernel. I must be behind! So most of you reading this will probably not need to load `fixltx2e` and can use `\textsubscript` out of the box, but if it doesn't work, you should probably update your kernel. The `fixltx2e` package can also be used with older kernels.)

Personally, I like to define a new command

```
\newcommand{\sbsc}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
```

To make life easier.

Note that `\textsubscript{}` enters math mode anyway, but for syntactic reasons I would recommend this over entering math mode explicitly for things that aren't mathematics. Logical structures and all of that.

If, however, you do want upright mathematics, `$\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{a}}$`, or even `$\text{x}_{\text{a}}$` would be the way to go.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\newcommand{\sbsc}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}

x\textsubscript{a} \\
x\sbsc{a} \\
$\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{a}}$ \\
$\text{x}_{\text{a}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textsubscript` has been incorporated in the kernel from release 2015/01/01.